# Solving the equation $ XA = A + 2X $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> How to solve $XA = A + 2X$ if $A$ being:
>   \begin{equation}
> A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     1    & 0   & 1 \\
>     0    & 2   & 1 \\
>     0    & 1   & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix} \\
> \end{equation}

I tried going $X = (A+2X)A^{-1}$ but I don't know how to get the 2X out from there.

Comment: Hint: write this as $X (A - 2 I) = A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you have $X(A-2I)=A$ thus $$ X = A\cdot (A-2I)^{-1}=...$$

Notice that $ (A-2I)^{-1}$ exists since $$A-2I =
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1    & 0   & 1 \\
    0    & 0   & 1 \\
    0    & 1   & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \det(A-2I)= 1$$

Comment: I understand the rest of the steps you showed, but when you get $X(A−2I)=A$ where does the $X$ go from the right hand side?

Comment: $2X = 2I\cdot X= X\cdot 2I$, the $X$ and $2I$ comute

Comment: Oh sorry I meant the right hand side of his equation, how $AX$ becomes $A$

Comment: Where do I have $AX$?

Comment: If we have $X\cdot B = A$ then $XB\cdot B^{-1} = AB^{-1}$ so $X= AB^{-1}$

Comment: Oh nevermind sorry I just got it, mindfart :'(
Thank you for the help!